# Bash Wildcard and Variable Usage

Tags: bash, wildcard, rsync, quoting, glob

What I'm trying to achieve is copying everything at source directory to destination directory by excluding the `workspace` directory, I have the following command to do so:

```
rsync -av --exclude='directory-name*/workspace' sourceDir destinationDir
```

which is working well, but if I try to use variable for the "directory-name":

```
VARIABLE_NAME="directory-name"
rsync -av --exclude='$VARIABLE_NAME*/workspace' sourceDir destinationDir
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded within single quotes. Neither are asterisks, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: replace the single quote with double quote

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: yup that works and I'll read everything at the link, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not expanded when put inside single quotes, use double quotes instead:

```
rsync -av --exclude="$VARIABLE_NAME"'*/workspace' sourceDir destinationDir
```